# Web Crawling and inbound link extracting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm searching for a c# function that takes a Url as a parameter and returns all the inbound url related to that url.

Comment: I've corrected your question, but in future would you please spend some effort in writing and using punctuation. So that everybody can easily understand what you are asking!

Comment: where do you searching ? because google have all ready some examples, what do you have find and you do not understand ? There is the part that you read the page, and the part that you get the context and process it.

Answer (score 0):

You can "download" webpages using the `WebClient` class:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";

WebClient client = new WebClient();
String source = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Then you need to search all URLS. I'd love to write a RegEx for you, if you'd put effort in finding the answer which you didn't, apparently.

Writing one of those Regular Expressions is rather hard because there are so many different things you have to match:

- Relative URL's
- Absolute URL's
- IP's
- You have to consider the `base` tag
- Only if they're in specific tags (`a`, `img`, `link`, `script`, and on and on)

Good luck with that

Answer (score 0):

From your description you want to find "inbound"? url's to a URL. If that is the case you would need to connect to an API to retrieve that information. I don't think Google has one but I do know they exist.